# Отступы у содержимого grid item

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 587px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 45px 29px;
  max-width: 1025px;
  padding-top: 92px;
}

.gallery_block-1 {
  background-color: #e6eef0;
}

.gallery_block-2 {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.gallery_block-3 {
  background-color: #fbfafa;
}

.gallery_block-4 {
  background-color: #e6eef0;
}

.gallery-label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.gallery-info-1 {
  padding-top: 109px;
}

.gallery-info-2 {}

.gallery-info-3 {}

.gallery-info-4 {}

.gallery-view {
  color: #696969;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container clearfix grid-1">

    <div class="gallery_block-1">
      <div class="gallery-info-1">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of whites.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_block-2">
      <div class="gallery-info-2">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of red.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_block-3">
      <div class="gallery-info-3">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of summer.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_block-4">
      <div class="gallery-info-4">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of black.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Нужно сверстать галерею из нескольких блоков. Как сделать так, чтоб при задании отступов содержимому каждый блок был разной высоты, как в макете? Пользуюсь css grid.

[image: Эта часть макета]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Какие отступы, каким елементам? Уточните, вопрос не понятный. А по факту не вижу в чем проблема, вам нужно создать сетку 3 строки, 2 колонки.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Yarik68/pen/qMYoyd
Задаю отступ у блока с текстом внутри итема, рядом стоящий блок тоже увеличивается
Лучше напишите, как правильно задать столбцы/строки, ибо так не доходит

Comment: исправьте ссылку, а лучше добавьте в сниппет ваш пример

Comment: Готово. Проверьте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размеры строк взяты на глаз.

Текст внутри можно позиционировать используя:

1. `position: absolute`- первый блок
2. `flex` - второй блок

```css
.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 225px 50px 225px;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  max-width: 1025px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.gallery__block {
  position: relative;
}
.gallery_block-1 {
  background-color: #e6eef0;
}

.gallery_block-2 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.gallery_block-3 {
  align-items: center;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: #fbfafa;
}

.gallery_block-4 {
  background-color: #e6eef0;
}

.gallery-label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gallery-info-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container clearfix grid-1">

    <div class="gallery__block gallery_block-1">
      <div class="gallery-info-1">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of whites.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__block gallery_block-2">
      <div class="gallery-info-2">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of red.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__block gallery_block-3">
      <div class="gallery-info-3">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of summer.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__block gallery_block-4">
      <div class="gallery-info-4">
        <h4 class="gallery-label">best of black.</h4>
        <div class="gallery-view"><a href="">veiw products</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Теперь ясно. Спасибо!